# How to replace the header of a file with the header of another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to replace the header in `file1.csv` with the header in `file2.csv`

```
file1.csv
"a","b","c"

file2.csv
"x","y","z"
```

I want `file1.csv`'s header as

```
"x","y","z"
```

Please tell me how to do it?  I tried

```
sed -i "1 s/^.*$/$file2.csv/" file1.csv
```

But it doesn't take the `""` (quotes). I want the header with the quotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you  insist to do it with `sed`:

```
( sed 1q file2.csv; sed 1d file1.csv ) >file3.csv && mv file3.csv file1.csv
```

Without `sed`:

```
( head -1 file2.csv; tail -n +2 file1.csv ) >file3.csv && mv file3.csv file1.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

With `gnu sed`, using `R` (read one line from the named file):

```
sed -i -e '1{R SOURCE' -e 'd}' DESTINATION
```

or with `ed`, open `DESTINATION` and read in `SOURCE` header after 1st line then delete 1st line:

```
ed -s DESTINATION <<\IN
1r ! head -n1 SOURCE
1d
w
q
IN
```

Comment: getting an error: Not a recognized flag: i

Comment: @Pooja25 - what's your operating system  and your sed version ? And how comes you didn't get that error with your initial `sed` command which also uses `-i` ? Regardless, the `ed` solution should work on any OS.

Comment: its windows, i doubt the same, all sed commands works except -i

Comment: @Pooja25: [_What_ Windows sed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/127567/560648)?

Comment: sorry, I use unix AIX

Answer (score 1):

If `file2.csv` contains only single line

```
sed -i "1 s/.*/$(< file2.csv)/" file1.csv
```

If `file2.csv` contains multiple lines

```
sed -i "1 s/.*/$(sed '1q' file2.csv)/" file1.csv
```

or

```
sed -i "1 s/.*/$(head -1 file2.csv)/" file1.csv
```

**Note:**

If line from `file2.csv` contains the delimiter character `/`, it will throw error like `` unknown option to `s' `` . Use different delimiter like `|` in such cases

Comment: getting an error sed: Not a recognized flag: i